# I'm unable to insert into MySQL using PHP (no errors are being displayed)

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$q= $_REQUEST["q"];
$r = $_REQUEST["r"];
$s = $_SESSION['empid'];
$max = 0;
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'employeesurvey';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$sql1 = "SELECT QuestionID FROM question";
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)){
    echo 'error2 php';
}
while($rw1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
   $Q = $rw1['QuestionID'] ;
   if ($max<$Q){
       $max = $Q;
   }
}
$Q = $Q+1;
$sql = "INSERT INTO question VALUES (".$Q.",'".$r."',".$s.",CURRENT_DATE(),".$q.",0)";
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
   echo "Error";
}
```

?>

The db, table names are all correct. I'm using xmlHttpRequest.open() to pass the values to this page
the call statement is:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint1.php?q=" + cid + "&r=" + question, true);
```

Im not getting any errors, nor the values are being inserted

Comment: Ouch. You never heard of auto increment fields in mysql?

Comment: I had used auto increment initially. But later i thought that it failed to insert because of some problem with auto incrementation which could have led to primary key conflict. So i tried incrementing myself

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)){
```

with these

```
$resultSet = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
if(!$resultSet){
```

And now replace this line:

```
while($rw1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
```

With this one

```
while($rw1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet)){
```

Reason is that you haven't executed query and stored the result set while at fetching record from result set, you are using direct query variable which is logically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

why are you making a simple thing this complicated by obtaining Question id from table just use autoincrement field in your mysql table or use insert_id 
and the problem is mysqli_fetch_array() function works on mysqli_query() function's output i.e. a object you are providing a string to a function which expects an object